# How to animate application icon in iOS?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, ipad, ios7

I have recently identified that in iOS 7 the clock icon is animating showing the real time.

[image: New clock icon]

Does anyone have a clue how to make your application icon animating? Or is that a feature of one single application?

Comment: @downvoter Of course I can't demonstrate my code or whatever because I have no clue if this is possible or not. Be clever.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19088977/can-we-make-animated-icons-for-ios-7-now-in-xcode

Comment: @0x7fffffff Ha! I was sure there is a question about it but haven't found in the search. Anyways there is no solid answer in that thread, but thanks for noticing.

Comment: Just pointing it out. It seems everyone knows that it can't be done without jailbreaking, but not how to actually do it using private API.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The iOS SDK does not allow you to change/animate your apps icon. Apple's own apps are ofcourse an exception.

Comment: I was thinking if Apple has technical possibilities to do this maybe there is something even undocumented which we missed.

Comment: Well if it is undocumented then how will you know about it? ;) maybe the jailbreak community has some new libraries but for AppStore Apps there is not way to do this.

Comment: In the same way how jailbreaks were written I guess `;)`

Comment: Add the jailbreak tag to your question, that might make jailbreak developers find your question.

Answer (score 2):

iOS doesn't allow you to use animated app icon. You need to have a look at https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/mobilehig/AppIcons.html

Answer (score 0):

There is no open API to do such a thing. Even if it exists, it's undocumented, and Apple would reject your app on review.

Answer (score 0):

This case is still in remain for Apple. Animated app icon for iOS is still unavailable/undocumented for us (developers).

Answer (score 0):

There is a way to do so. It's called "alternate icons".

API doc: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiapplication/2806815-supportsalternateicons

Example: https://medium.com/ios-os-x-development/dynamically-change-the-app-icon-7d4bece820d2

Comment: I guess this technique will change the icon from the app on demand and not on the background when the application is not running.

Comment: @VisioN, probably you can use background tasks.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/backgroundtasks