How can I dynamically change app name and icon for my react native app in real-time?
There's this project that I am working on, using React Native for Android and iOS devices. My client wants me to change app icon and app name when certain event is triggered. Is it even possible? If yes, how can I achieve this. Please help me with this problem statement.
Tried passing dynamic values to main.json but it didn't go as expected.

You can store the app name in a state variable (using React’s useState) and update it based on the triggered event.
Then, use the updated state variable wherever you display the app name in your app.

Or you can use react-native-change-icon package.

AFAIK you can’t: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19361716/5905466
You can define a icon only at build time and change the name depending on the region.

You can programmatically change the icon using react-native-change-icon
, but you must include icons assets in your build. For the app name, idk if there is a good solution, but if you're using expo take a look at this : multiple app variants. Maybe it can fit your case
